# Song "This Loneliness" written by carmine Coppola "

Tags: songwriter

When was the song, "This Loneliness" written by Carmine Coppola?

Comment: I suppose early 1972 (because is part of The GodFather soundtrack)

Comment: In "The Godfather Legacy" by Harlan Lebo the author states that the music "was performed on set by Carmine Coppola playing one of his older compositions". Interestingly the GEMA database entry for the tune names Giuseppe Verdi as composer and Coppola as arranger, but I can't identify which Verdi work the tune is 'borrowed' from.

Comment: If have some sympathy for the close vote, but the comments now contain most to be asked for.